# Need Help OpenGL + C

Tags: c, opengl

im tring to implement C code in openGl to show date in my solor system program. but im getting error 
which basically sayed as follow:

> error: invalic operands to binary * (have 'char *' and 'char *')

My code as follow :

```
void showDate(void)
{
    int days, years;
    char str[30];
    char *ch;

    // ....... some code

    // and here it's giving that error in for statment
    for( ch * str; *ch; ch++){
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, (int) *cha
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Post your actual code, the actual error you're getting and give your question a descriptive title. That you need help is obvious and OpenGL and C are already mentioned in the tags.

Comment: This is actual code people, just out of context.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is wrong. It should look like this:

```
for (ch = str; *ch; ch++)
{
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, (int) *ch);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help ya it was like tht i fixed it ; but i do have question about declaring days and years. Can i declar them as  int days = 0; int years = 0; or they shoud be Glint days =0; Glint years =0. Cz i dont know really whts the different

Comment: It really shouldn't matter, but I would use GLint just to be safe.